# How do I calculate an inverse bind-pose matrix for COLLADA?

Tags: 3d, mathematics, collada

I want to port a rigged mesh from a custom format to COLLADA. The bones I have define a position for the bone (local) and a matrix that transforms the child-bones' positions into the next-higher coordinate space. (The position of the root usually is {0, 0, 0}.)

How can I convert these to the inverse bind-pose matrices used for COLLADA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate (multiply together) your local transforms to get a world transform for each joint. Invert each world matrix.